# C# dll running on 64-bit machine

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit

I have created a C# dll to print PDFs with Acrobat.  This is called from Microsoft Dynamics NAV.  When this is run on a 32-bit machine, it works with no problems.  When we install it on a 64-bit machine, we get the following error

Could not invoike the member PrintToPrinter.  The OLE control or Automation server returned the following message:
The requested memeber does not exist, or the call tried to set the value of a read-only property.

What can I do to get this to run on the 64-bit Windows 7 machine?  I set it to target x86, I have also tried created installers for x86 and x64 but I keep getting the same error message.

Here is my code.

```
[ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public class CCB_PDFPrinting
{
    public void PrintToPrinter(string FileName, string PrinterName)
    {
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"Acrobat.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/n /t " + FileName + " \"" + PrinterName + "\"";
        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit(1000);
        proc.CloseMainWindow();
        proc.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your dll reference any COM objects or other third party compnents?

Comment: Sounds like one of your libraries also needs to target x86.

Comment: No.  I creat a process setting properties in the StartInfo and start the process.  Then close it.

Comment: donot know if it is gud comment but i think you should try and build for `x64`

Comment: Originally I had it set to target any pc.  It's my understanding that a 32-bit application can't call a 64-bit.

Comment: sounds like your caller assembly is not compatible with x64

Answer (score 1):

You can set the process to run as a **32 bit** process even on a **64 bit** machine.

This will force it to use your 32 bit libraries.

Use `CorFlags.exe` and set `/32bit+` flag (perhaps as a post-build step of your application).